# Не удается запустить модуль после импорта в Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

Создал 3 файла для экспорта модуля:

setup:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='seach4letter',
    version='1.0',
    description='Первый созданный модуль для практики',
    autor='Рудаков Дмитрий',
    autor_email='dmi-gorshkov@mail.ru',
    url='headfirstlabs.com',
    py_modules=['seach4letter']
)
```

Экспортировал. После этого импортировал этот модуль через командную строку:

```
C:\Users\администратор\.PyCharm2018 .3\config\scratches\dist>py
seach4letter-1.0.tar.gz
Processing c:\users\администратор\.pycharm2018 .3\config\scratch
ter-1.0.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: seach4letter
Running setup.py install for seach4letter ... done
Successfully installed seach4letter-1.0
```

Но когда пытаюсь его импортировать, появляется ошибка:

```
import seach4letter
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.3.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundl e\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seach4letter'
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Второй файл - это seach4letter.py, как я понимаю.  А какой третий файл?

Comment: Второй файл - README.txt

Comment: Нашел. Модуль импортируется в C:\Users\администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages

Но почему? должен импортироваться в C:\Users\администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib

Comment: Сторонние модули и должны устанавливаться в site-packages

Comment: Но в этом случае как его импортировать? import seach4letter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.3.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seach4letter'

Comment: Но в этом случае как его импортировать? 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.3.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'seach4letter'

Comment: Модуль `seach4letter.py` называется? Скрипт запускается тем же интерпретатором, под которым модуль был установлен?

Comment: Попробуйте скрипт, где импортируется ваш модуль, запустить не через IDE